# Get access to variable inside HTML from component for Angular 2 Typescript

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

I have the following code to display a modal popup from ng-bootstrap. In the example there is a button, which when clicked, triggers an `open(content)` function to display the view. As you can see, `#content` is defined in the HTML template. However, this is not exactly what I want. I want to get rid of the button completely and trigger this popup programmatically. Therefore I need to somehow get the reference to `#content` in my component.

```
<template #content let-c="close" let-d="dismiss">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
    <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" (click)="d('Cross click')">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
  </div>

  <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" (click)="c('YES')">YES</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" (click)="c('NO')">NO</button>
  </div>
</template>

<!--I dont want this button to trigger the template in my actual app. So imagine this code is not here!-->
<button class="btn btn-lg btn-outline-primary" (click)="open(content)">Launch demo modal</button>
```

Code of `open(content)` in component:

```
open(content) {
    this.modalService.open(content).result.then((result) => {
        this.closeResult = `Closed with: ${result}`;
    }, (reason) => {
        this.closeResult = `Dismissed ${this.getDismissReason(reason)}`;
    });
}
```

For example, I want to do something like:

```
// In this example, content is undefined as I am not and can not pass #content through from the HTML since it is not triggered by a button press like the demo
if (myCustomCondition == true ) {
    this.modalService.open(content).result.then((result) => {
      this.closeResult = `Closed with: ${result}`;
    }, (reason) => {
      this.closeResult = `Dismissed ${this.getDismissReason(reason)}`;
    });
}
```

[image: content is not defined]

Comment: It seems to be working for me, could you please try to replication here in [this plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/mPQQsRvlbBQj0r8LxsiX?p=preview)?

Comment: Hey Pankaj. The code is working. But my question is, how can I change it so that I can trigger the open code from the component. Reason is that I do not have access to "content" to call if (myCondition == true ) { open(content) } As shown in the updated question

Comment: @user172902 so write the if statement? I don't understand what the issue is..

Comment: Don't understood, please elaborate mire on it..

Comment: The issue is that I dont have access to the variable #content from inside my component. So I cant call open(content) unless the event is triggered from the HTML code where content is present. I have updated the question a bit more to explain this. Hope it helps

Comment: @user172902 write the if statement inside the `open(content)` method which will wrap the `modelService` or write it inside the html ?

Comment: Have you tried to use @Viewchild?

Comment: You want to pass the `<template>` element to `this.modalService(...)`?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer, That is exactly what I want. The answer provided below will not work. I might have phrased the question wrongly. Imagine I dont have any button click at all to trigger the popup. I need a way to trigger the popup using code. I will update the question completely

Comment: Angular2 currently doesn't allow to create a `<template>` element. It is used only internally but it never becomes a real DOM element. What does your modal component expect? A `<template>` element, or a `TemplateRef` instance?

Comment: Hi all, sorry about the confusion. I have updated the whole question once again to make it extra clear. @GünterZöchbauer, Does that mean there is no way of achieving what I wanted?

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs a `TemplateRef` can be passed https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/modal

therefore this should work

```
  @ViewChild('content') content:TemplateRef;

  open() {
    this.modalService.open(this.content).result.then((result) => {
      this.closeResult = `Closed with: ${result}`;
    }, (reason) => {
      this.closeResult = `Dismissed ${this.getDismissReason(reason)}`;
    });
  }
```

Comment: Angular doesn't like the syntax apparently. It gives me the following error  as soon as I added @ViewChild('content') contentTemplateRef (and nothing else). 

inline template:0:5 caused by: formGroup expects a FormGroup instance. Please pass one in.

Comment: Sorry, forgot a `:` - fixed.

Comment: Thanks for helping out @Gunter. I am still getting the same error " formGroup expects a FormGroup instance. Please pass one in." straight after I put @ViewChild('content') content:TemplateRef<any> in.I had to import TemplateRef and <any> for the syntax to work. The example is not using a form so I dont know why it wants a form group or some sort?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have any idea how `formGroup` could be involved here.